# Django : How to install mysql

Tags: mysql, django, pip

I want to use mysql with django but I have problems

I tried this with pip :

`(env) C:\mat20>pip install MySQL-python==2.7.1`

and I have the error:

No distributions matching the version for `MySQL-python==2.7.1`

after I tried :

`(env) C:\mat20>pip install MySQL-python`

and I have the error :

`error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat`

What is the problem ?

Comment: apt-get install python-mysqldb will work on debian

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this error `error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat` by

`mingw`

or try Install c++ compiler `here`

Comment: and about  easy_install ?

Comment: No @Patrice I want you try second one and let me know...!

Comment: Until now, I used sqlite. I want to use mysql because It is the better solution. I don't know pymysql..